# How to compare two complex objects using json or xml

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, .net

I am having two complex classes.
I have to compare both objects are or equal or not.
For that, I converted the objects to Json string and then Jobject.
Then comparing with `jobject.deepEquals` method.
The problem is
It is always showing as not equal, due to
One object has null in its few properties, whereas the other has empty in its properties.

Logically, both are the same.
So I have to overcome this.
Any suggestions, please advise.

Step1 : converting object to Json string using newtonsoft.
Step2: converting the Json to string jobject
Step3: comparing two jobjects using deepequals method.

The below classes are just samples.
The comparison can be achieved by very minimal code using `json.but` the problem comes as null and empty.
I have to convert any class null values to be empty or empty values to be null to make the classes equal.

The class has four lists of classes.

```
 Public class Example { 
 Public list<ClassA> classA{get;set;} 
Public list<ClassB> classB{get;set;} 
Public list<ClassC> ClassC{get;set;}
Public list<ClassD> classD{get;set;} 
Public string identifier{get;set;} }
}
Public Class classA
{
Public int value {get; set;}
Public string text {get;set;}
Public Datetime date{get; set;}
}

Public Class ClassB
{
Public string text1 {get; set;}
Public string text2 {get;set;}
Public Datetime date1{get; set;}
Public list<CSettings> setting{get; 
set;}
and so on.
}
```

Comment: Comparing two c# objects by converting them to json sesms both over complex and very fragile. Json objects can only be properly compared in javascript. Why not implement a compare-method on the object in c#? If not possible, please extend your question with the limitations you are facing.

Comment: Hi Andreas, Thank you for the comment.I extended my question.

Comment: When would you consider an instance of ClassA equal to an instance of  ClassB?

Comment: The instance of Example should equal with the other instance of Example. All property values in the example class instance should equal with the other instance of Example class

Comment: What if your lists within each object are differ only in ordering? Are they equal or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is only a problem with "" and null comparision, you can simply replace empty string to null, like this:

```
var obj1 = new Test("a", "");
var obj2 = new Test("a", null);

var js1 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj1);
var js2 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj2);

js1 = js1.Replace("\"\"", "null");

JToken.DeepEquals(JToken.Parse(js1), JToken.Parse(js2));
// true
```

If you need, in different scenarios you can also use:

```
new JsonSerializer
{
    NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
};
```